# Http Request iOS 11.2 failes

Tags: http, swift4, ios11.2

I try to make a http request to my server to get a **JSON**, but every time I try it I get this error message.

> 2018-03-26 16:53:32.477431+0200 S_Buddy[40041:3435695] [] nw_socket_connect connect failed (fd 8, 172.227.96.127:443 stream, pid: 40041, sanitized url: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml, tls): [64] Host is down
>   2018-03-26 16:53:32.479737+0200 S_Buddy[40041:3435695] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x60400017f5c0]: 3:64 Err(64)
>   2018-03-26 16:53:32.480346+0200 S_Buddy[40041:3435695] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, 64)
>   2018-03-26 16:53:32.480465+0200 S_Buddy[40041:3435695] Task <2DA19979-F9F3-4F4B-92EB-AF8BE012833F>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:64])
>   2018-03-26 16:53:32.480970+0200 S_Buddy[40041:3435696] Task <2DA19979-F9F3-4F4B-92EB-AF8BE012833F>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=64, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000044cae0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=64, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=64}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml?c9911b4d481e6ada019ba2d93f6cf780, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml?c9911b4d481e6ada019ba2d93f6cf780, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

My **info.plist** configuration is:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ecb.europa.eu</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTSLVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

My iOS target is 10 and I use Swift 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've found from similar questions on the web is that they used the following keys, including a few different than the ones you are already using:

```
<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<false/>
<key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.0</string>
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
<key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
<false/>                
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<false/>
<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>TLSv1.0</string>

<key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<true/>
```

I have not tested this with your particular website.